# Is it right to say you made me make a typo?

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, american-english

If you're at school writing something down and and someone bumps into your shoulder and made you mispell something as a result, is it right to tell at the person who bumped into you "you made me make a typo"?
(By writing down, I mean using a pen to mark a piece of paper)

Comment: Yes. "you made me make a typo." or you can say "I made a typo because of you". I would say either of these.

Comment: I would say _neither_ of those.

Comment: I could suggest a 'scribo' (for 'scribographical error'), but not seriously.

Comment: @Werrucktlerner - please clarify urgently - do you mean 'writing' in the usual sense (producing marks on paper by hand with a pen, pencil, etc)? That's what we mean when we talk about 'writing something down'.

Comment: The problem is that if I am writing something down, e.g. _The cat sat on the mat_, and someone bumps me so the last letter looks like a 'p', I don't just leave it, I correct it, or, if I am making a fair copy, I get a fresh sheet of paper, or maybe some correction fluid. If the bump produces a jagged line, that's not the handwritten equivalent of a 'typo'; it's spoilt or spoiled writing.

Comment: @Werrucktlerner - how can someone _make_ you misspell something?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Only the devil can make you do that.

Answer (score 2):

No. A typo is a typographical error:

[American Heritage Dictionary "typographical error"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=typographical%20error)
"A mistake in printing, typesetting, or typing, especially one caused by striking an incorrect key on a keyboard."

A typo is an error in spelling, that is, an incorrect letter or symbol.

Being bumped by another person when you are writing can't make you produce an incorrect letter. It will probably result in a smear or scrawl.

(The OP asked specifically about "writing something down". That phrase means to make marks on paper with a pen or pencil, and doesn't apply to any sort of typing.)

Comment: Nobody I've ever knows has said "smear" or "scrawl". It's always a "typo" or a "mess up"

Comment: Nobody _**I**_ have ever _known_ has said "typo" or a "mess up" for that situation. I have heard "smear" or "scrawl".

Comment: Shame on whoever voted down Jack O'Flaherty's correct answer.

Comment: Did someone bump your arm, Tyler M, when you were typing 'known'?

Comment: When I was at teenage school in the 1960s, ball-point pens (we called them 'Biros') were banned; we had to use fountain pens, usually quite cheap ones. A common sport was to jog someone and make them create a blot. Extra kudos if the nib broke.

Comment: We were provided with blotting paper. Some boys who were real scoundrels would put some in their mouth, chew it to a pulp, spit it on the desk, add some ink, form it into a ball, and use a ruler as a catapult to fling it across the classroom. Most kudos was from making it land on someone's written work, but their shirt or face were good too.

Comment: "A mistake in printing, typesetting, or typing, especially one caused by striking an incorrect key on a keyboard."  This definition perfectly well fits the scenario described by the OP. "A mistake in ... typing .... caused by striking an incorrect key".  They have struck the incorrect key as a result of someone nudging them, but they've still struck the incorrect key, haven't they?

Comment: @rjpond That doesn't apply to the OP question, which specifically asked about "writing something down". That means using a pen or pencil to  make marks on paper.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty You're right.  Perhaps I misread it.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it a "typo".

When I write "corect" instead of "correct" because I'm careless (I know how to spell it correctly but didn't) that's a careless mistake. When I write "corect" instead of "correct" because I think the word has only one "r", that is a spelling error. When I write "cprrect" instead of "correct" because my fingers hit the wrong key on the keyboard, that's a typo. When I write "corrct" instead of "correct" because my keyboard is broken and doesn't let me type the letter "e", that's a keyboard malfunction.

If I hit the wrong keys because someone bumps into me, and the wrong letters appear on the screen or on paper, I wouldn't call that a typo. I "typo" is a mistake by me, hitting the wrong keys. Someone bumping into me can result in messed up text, but it doesn't cause me to make a mistake - a mistake would be my fault, and this isn't.

I would say "you messed up my writing". There are probably many other ways to express this. Importantly, you want to put the blame onto the right person.

BTW. When writing on paper with a pen or pencil, you can't make "typos". A typo is today a mistake hitting the wrong key on the keyboard; in previous times it was making mistakes during typesetting.